# php most log in to access page

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

hello i need some help!

i have made a login button for my website and when you log in with a account i want it to transfer the user to another page. but if you are logged out i do not want outlogged users to be able to access that page!

here is the php code!
[image]

sorry if it is a picture there  is something wrrong when i try to paste in the code :(

to see the html and css code go to my website http://pixelatedore.zapto.org/ and do CTRL + u

Comment: You need to read the editing help and learn how to format code.

Comment: You have some syntax errors in there. Try to comprehend the difference between control structures with and without brackets and use `if…elseif…else` instead of `if…else…else`

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: On line 7, you have mispelt `$connect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a copy of your code with adjustments:

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['username'])); // protects from mysql injections
$password = sha1(trim($_POST['password'])); // SHA1 - encrypts password (make sure this is the same in your update/create user script
if ($username && $password) {
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die("Couldn't connect!");
    mysql_select_db("pixelatedore", $connect) or die("Couldn't find db");
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'", $connect);
    if (mysql_num_rows($query)>0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password) {
                header('Location loginconfirm.php');
                $_SESSION['username']=$username;
                exit;
            } else {
                echo 'incorrect password!';
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "That user doesn't exist!";
    }
}
?>
```

On the page you don't want them to access (assuming its the loginconfirm.php) add this to the top:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: /loggedout-page/or/home-page.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when a user is logging in, you store one information that will identify the user with `$_SESSION.`

So on each page you don't want access for a unidentified user, you just need to add something like this :

```
   if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
   {
      echo "You need to be logged in to view this page !";
      // Or any redirection to the main page for example

   }

   Else
   {
      Your page here
   }
```

The `isset($variable)` checks if this variable is defined.

When the user press the loggout button, you just need to call `unset($_SESSION['username']);`